# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions, there is something missing in the hypothesis?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was reading an Analysis book and saw the following problem:

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be an sequence of functions such that $|f_n(x)| \neq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in X$ and such that $\left|\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}\right|\leq c <1$ for all $x \in X$ and for $n$ sufficiently large. Show that $\sum |f_n(x)|$ and $\sum f_n(x)$ are both uniformly convergent.

This seem a very easy problem if at least one $|f_n|$ is bounded for sufficiently large $n$, but as you all can see, this hypothesis does not exist in the description of the problem.

My question is: this additional hypothesis is required for this stamement to become true?

Comment: Indeed it is necessary.  Example: let $f_1\colon(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be the identity and $f_{n+1}=cf_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. A counter-example is $f_n(x)=\frac 1 {2^{n}x}$ on $(0,1)$. $(f_n(x))$ does not tend to  $0$ uniformly so $\sum f_n$ does not converge uniformly.